# Table Layout column taxt right align

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

in TableLayout i have to align my text in first column to right and third column text to left (my second column is just dummy column for spacing). aligning  right  is  problem . I  also have one concern if the content in second column doesn't fit in one line that how to make it continue  on second line because now if i am entering big text in second column now  it is trying to fit in one line and going out of mobile screen width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:stretchColumns="0,2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget43" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/red">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget36" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView is in Rightassaasas"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget33"
        android:layout_width="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget36" android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget37"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget38" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white">
        <TextView android:layout_width="2dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/green">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout seems unnecessarily complex, you really just need a single LinearLayout with the two TextViews with the gravity set properly.  You can use layout_margin to create the spacing for your "middle column", something like this:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget43" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget33"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget36" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView is in Rightassaasas"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:background="@color/red" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget38" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:gravity="left" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:background="@color/green" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```